# Is there a Microsoft Calendar API that returns Ids of recurrent events

Tags: graph, outlook

I am using the following API to get the events from Microsoft Calendar:

https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events

I only need the events for today and tomorrow, hence I put a date startDate and endDate in the URL above.

Now If I create a recurrent event on say today (occurring daily at 4:00 PM for example), I get all the information on that event that is returned in a recurrent JSON key.

I do not get the same event the next day.

Is there any API that returns all the ids of recurrent event for a range of dates or current month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}